# How do I convert a link into a button using PHP?

Tags: php

Can anyone skillful with PHP please help me with this question?

I want to essentially, convert a link into a button instead. Here is the relevant part of the code.

Basically, when the user clicks a different link (which is not relevant here), PHP will then generate another link called "Add Event" (this is the relevant one). It is the second line of this code that I am struggling to convert:

index.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['v'])){
     echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
     if(isset($_GET['f'])){
         include("eventform.php");
```

It is attached to this file as well:

eventform.php

```
<form name='eventform' method='POST' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo $year;?>&v=true&add=true">

<table width='400px'>
    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Title</td>
        <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle'> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Detail</td>
        <td width='250px'> <textarea name='txtdetail'> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td td colspan='2'align='center'> <input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add Event'> </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Basically, when you click the "Add Event" link, a form is generated. I want to essentially turn the "Add Event" link into an "Add Event" button. It will serve the same purpose- when the button is clicked, a form is generated. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: You could always style the link to _look_ like a button

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this? I tried looking at inserting span classes or div tags, but I am really stuck on how to do this as I keep getting error messages. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, but there are just _way_ too many examples out there for how to do this, and the specific way to do it would depend on exactly how you wanted it to look.

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Heres a quickie example btn (which doesnt look like a n OS button): https://jsfiddle.net/b3nhedhx/

Comment: That is fantastic!!! Thank you so much for your kind help! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could style the anchor tag to look like a button.

On the second line of your code, add a class to the anchor element named btn like so:

```
<a class="btn" //rest of your code>
```

and then in your CSS file

```
.btn {
     padding: 15px 30px;
     color: white;
     background: blue;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
```

When it is rendered out to the view, it should have the appearance of a button.